# kafka multi-partition only one can receive message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am new to kafka.I read the quick start and create a topic named 'test' with 4 partitions,but when send messages to the topic I find all messages are saved in partition-0,the other three partitions are empty why?

there is my java code to send messages

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
         producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test", "message",Integer.toString(i)));

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html)

`If no partition is specified but a key is present a partition will be chosen using a hash of the key.`

Since you are passing the same key, it is being sent to the same partition.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
     producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test", "message"+i,Integer.toString(i)));

}
```

I have randomized the message by changing to `"message"+i`